# Symfony 1.4: Merging values from multiple settings.yml files

Tags: php, symfony1, yaml

Our organiziation is running 60+ Symfony 1.4 sites and we are looking to globalize the settings files (settings.yml, app.yml). We'd like to have a simple PHP require in the /config/settings|app.yml files and create site-specific settings in the apps/frontend/config/settings|app.yml files. Implementing this setup with the app.yml is not a problem. Settings from the /config/app.yml combine/merge with the apps/frontend/config/app.yml. When we try to implement the settings.yml, however, the settings are overridden by the apps/frontend/config/settings.yml -- specifically the enabled_modules, which we'd like to be able to have sites merge their own specific modules with the global ones.

The link below has the following verbiage:

"...Some configuration files can be defined in several config/ sub-directories contained in the project directory structure.
When the configuration is compiled, the values from all the different files are merged according to a precedence order:..."

So, I'm assuming merging the settings.yml file values is possible and I'm doing something wrong.

http://www.symfony-project.org/referenc ... on_cascade

I appreciate any help that ya'll can provide. Thanks in advance!!